# Does nginx serve compressed files, if brotli_static is on, even though brotli is off?

Tags: nginx, brotli

I want to gain a clear understanding of the module ngx_brotli's directives. Specifically I need to understand, how brotli_static works. If brotli is off, I expect that the value of brotli_static will be ignored. Is this correct? How I imagine the behaviour, is that files will be compressed once, then the precompressed files will be served, if both brotli and brotli_static are on. If only brotli is on but brotli_static is off, I expect that files will be compressed anew, each time they are requested.

I compiled nginx with the ngx_brotli module. So far there are no apparent errors, but I want to make sure everything is set up correcty. My setup looks as follows:

```
http {
    brotli  off;
    brotli_static  on;
    brotli_types  *;
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location xyz {
            brotli  on;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If brotli is off, I expect that the value of brotli_static will be ignored. Is this correct?

No, if `brotli off;` is set, it has no influence on the `brotli_static` setting. The reason being is that `ngx_brotli` actually consists of two modules (1 - filter and 2 - static).

The `brotli` directive controls on-the fly compression, it belongs to the filter module.

The `brotli_static` controls whether pre-compressed files are looked up and used. It belongs to the static module.

So thus configuration like the following is perfectly valid and usable when you have precompressed files and don't want to spend CPU on dynamic compression:

```
brotli off;
brotli_static  on;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't been active on stackoverflow lately. So I understand that ngx_brotli and brotli_static are two modules, but where does the precompressed file,  that brotli_static uses come from? Is it automatically generated the first time someone makes a request and then cached for further requests? Is it generated independantly of the 'brotli' directive?

Comment: @BenediktJensen the precompressed file has to be generated by yourself, automated or manually. You have to use `brotli --best` for optimal results. See [this guide](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/brotli-static)